# Dot Net and Java Culture Codes

Tags: java, .net, globalization, culture

I've been tasked with the awesome job of generating a look-up table for our application culture information.  The columns I need to generate data for are:

- Dot Net Code
- Version
- Culture Name
- Country Name
- Language Name
- Java Country Code
- Java Language Code
- Iso Country Code
- Iso Language Code

I have found the globalization name space, but I'm sure someone out there has asked the same question, or there is a table already available.

Thanks for any help

Comment: AFAIK, Java does not use a proprietary set of codes for languages/countries, so What do you mean by Java country/language code?

Comment: Well, what i mean is that for .NET we have "en-us", is there a similar type of code for Java?

Comment: Yes, but Java uses the ISO codes http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java uses the 2-letter ISO country and language codes. I recommend getting rid of the "Java Country Code" and "Java Language Code" fields in your lookup table, since they would be redundant.

I assume that wherever you get your ISO [country](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) and [language](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) codes, you'll find their corresponding names in English. However, the Java [Locale](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) API will give also you the localized names for the country and language, if you need them. (I.e., what is America called in Japan?)

For example, you can do this:

```
Locale l = Locale.ITALY;
System.out.println(l.getDisplayCountry() + ": " + l.getDisplayLanguage());
System.out.println(l.getDisplayCountry(l) + ": " + l.getDisplayLanguage(l));
```

Which, running in the US English locale prints:

```
Italy: Italian 
Italia: italiano
```

Note that you can obtain 3-letter ISO codes from the Locale class, but when constructing them, be sure to only use 2-letter codes.

Answer (score 2):

That's strange, the last time I visited this page, someone had beaten me to posting the links to the Java references for Localization.

However, since their post is gone, here's what I was writing before they beat me to it.

Java uses two ISO standards for localization with [java,util.Locale](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

- 2-letter [ISO-639](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/English_list.php) for language.
- 2-letter [ISO-3166](http://www.iso.ch/iso/en/prods-services/iso3166ma/02iso-3166-code-lists/list-en1.html) for country.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses Locales to store this information. Most of all the information you need regarding it can be found on Sun's [Internationalization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/locale/) page. Java uses a syntax similar to the "en-us" syntax, however rather than using a hyphen it delineates with an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you mean Localization or Internationalization or i18n.

Try this tutorial:
    http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/index.html

Good Luck,
Randy Stegbauer